# UPDATE двух таблиц или 2 запроса?

Tags: sql

делаю вот таких два запроса для обновления данных в транзакцией:

```
UPDATE balance_1 SET btc= $btc WHERE login = user_1
UPDATE balance_2 SET btc= $btc WHERE login = user_2
```

Собственно вопрос, как обновить одним запросом и стоит ли это делать?

Comment: Если у вас таблиц столько, сколько у вас пользователей (судя по users_1, users_2), то это уже неверно, что бы вы там и как не хотели уже обновлять

Comment: В один запрос обновить две таблицы невозможно. разве что триггерами на первую. но не похоже что запросы у вас как то связаны между собой. И да, хранить пользователей/пароли в двух таблицах очень странное решение

Comment: Ну это пример, таблиц всего две, а хранится собственно будет баланс пользователей.

Comment: @Mike обновить две таблицы можно)  типа `UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.columnName = 51, table2.columnName = 5 WHERE table1.id = 1 AND table2.id = 64`

Comment: Поправил вопрос для наглядности.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В стандартном SQL ? БД то не указана

Comment: mysqli использую

Comment: Логика понятна, и все же так стоит делать вроде вместо 2х запросов один, значит работать должно быстрее, или нет?

Comment: Юрий, у вас проблема с производительностью? Мне кажется, что попахивает преждевременной оптимизацией. Если на 2 ух этих таблицах стоят индексы, то запросы должны выполняться моментально. Я сомневаюсь, что будет профит в плане производительности, и вообще апдейт сразу двух таблиц выглядит дико...

Comment: Да, были проблемы с нагрузкой, слишком много запросов, поэтому решил сделать хранение данныхв 3х таблицах и делать выборку отдельно для разных сервисов.